# Slicing List items in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have ordered list of string elements which I need to iterate.. starting from specific element/item from the list until the end.

The list that I have:

```
ip_list = ['input1','input2','input3',....,'input10']
```

I wanted to iterate from any given element (which would be dynamic on each run) for example consider `input3` currently till the end of List.

So I wanted to achieve something like this:

```
for item in ip_list[input3:]:
    # my logic base
```

I have searched out that, in Python, we can slice the list with positional base but not on value base.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Can you show an example?

Comment: Your question is very unclear and not specific to anything, you should show your data and your expected output, and stuff you already tried to do with it. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `lst[lst.index(x):]`?

Comment: hope it help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes using `index()` finds the position of an element in a list.

So if your list looks like this:

```
ip_list = ['input1','input2','input3']
```

And you want to initerate from `input3` onward then using `ip_list.index('input3')` returns the position of `input3` (so 2).

You then just have to slice the list in the normal way (as if you were doing `ip_list[2:]`) but using `index()`:

```
for item in ip_list[ip_list.index('input3'):]:
    # my logic base
```

See [Finding the index of an item given a list containing it in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

`list[list.index(value):]`

see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

**list.index(x[, start[, end]])**

Return zero-based index in the list of the first item whose value is x. Raises a ValueError if there is no such item.

The optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in the slice notation and are used to limit the search to a particular subsequence of the list. The returned index is computed relative to the beginning of the full sequence rather than the start argument.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution based on [iterators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) that works with any iterable, not just lists:

```
def iterate_from(iterable, start_value):
    # step 1: get an iterator
    itr = iter(iterable)

    # step 2: advance the iterator to the first matching value
    first_value = next(value for value in itr if value == start_value)

    # step 3: yield the remaining values
    yield first_value
    yield from itr
```

Here I used the [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) function to get an iterator from the iterable, and the [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) function to move that iterator forward. You may also be interested in [What does the "yield" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do).

You would use it like this:

```
ip_list = ['input{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 11)]

for ip in iterate_from(ip_list, 'input7'):
    print(ip)

# output:
# input7
# input8
# input9
# input10
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
ip_list = ['input{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,10)]
for item in ip_list[3:]:
    print(item)
```